# Cordova resolveLocalFileSystemURL error code 1000 in Android

Tags: android, cordova

When i use cordova function resolveLocalFileSystemURL with some type of file uri (like content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/some_doc) i have an error with code 1000. I use cordova 5.1 and 5 version of Android installed on smartphone.

adb logcat shows this:

```
W/System.err(28721): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
W/System.err(28721):    at org.apache.cordova.file.ContentFilesystem.getFileMetadataForLocalURL(ContentFilesystem.java:130)
W/System.err(28721):    at org.apache.cordova.file.Filesystem.exists(Filesystem.java:130)
W/System.err(28721):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(FileUtils.java:624)
W/System.err(28721):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$400(FileUtils.java:51)
W/System.err(28721):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$14.run(FileUtils.java:383)
W/System.err(28721):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$25.run(FileUtils.java:566)
W/System.err(28721):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err(28721):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err(28721):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Is it some way to open this files with cordova?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.  In Android 5, the cursor is now a DocumentCursor not a Media Cursor which means it was looking for the wrong column.  When the column was not found, the plugin tries to set a primitive long to null which caused the NullPointerException.

```
@Override
public JSONObject getFileMetadataForLocalURL(LocalFilesystemURL inputURL) throws FileNotFoundException {
    long size = -1;
    long lastModified = 0;
    Uri nativeUri = toNativeUri(inputURL);
    String mimeType = resourceApi.getMimeType(nativeUri);
    Cursor cursor = openCursorForURL(nativeUri);
    try {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            size = resourceSizeForCursor(cursor);
            Long modified = lastModifiedDateForCursor(cursor);
            if (modified != null)
                lastModified = modified.longValue();
        } else {
            // Some content providers don't support cursors at all!
            CordovaResourceApi.OpenForReadResult offr = resourceApi.openForRead(nativeUri);
            size = offr.length;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }

    JSONObject metadata = new JSONObject();
    try {
        metadata.put("size", size);
        metadata.put("type", mimeType);
        metadata.put("name", name);
        metadata.put("fullPath", inputURL.path);
        metadata.put("lastModifiedDate", lastModified);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return metadata;
}

protected Long lastModifiedDateForCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED);
    if (columnIndex == -1) {
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED);
    }
    if (columnIndex != -1) {
        String dateStr = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        if (dateStr != null) {
            return Long.parseLong(dateStr);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue.  When you say you have fixed this issue, do you mean this is now in the current release of cordova, v5.1.1 ?

Comment: I forked the github project and submitted a pull request.  Still has not been pulled.  However,  there are a ton of other problems with file plugin and android 5.  I have not worked out the other issues.